# Calculating $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^{6}}}\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: integration

I can't calculate the Integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^{6}}}dx
 $$

any help would be great!

p.s I know it converges, I want to calculate it.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(1/4)}{6\Gamma(3/4)}\approx 0.874$.

Answer (score 2):

Use substitution $u=x^6$ and $B$ function:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^6}}dx=\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1u^{-\frac{3}{4}}(1-u)^{-\frac{1}{2}}du=\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1u^{\frac{1}{4}-}(1-u)^{\frac{1}{2}-1}du=\frac{1}{6}B(x,y)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})}$$

Answer (score 1):

Doing the substitution first $x^3 = \cos\theta$ , then $\theta/2 = t$, would lead us to a simpler integral:
$$
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{3\sqrt{\cos\theta}} d\theta = \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 \frac{2}{3\sqrt{1 - 2\sin^2t}} dt
$$
and this is [elliptic integral of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html), hence no closed form. For the numerical value please refer to vadim123's comment.